# How to declare global types in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I want to have a global type in my simple typescript project.
The program just run a simple calculation in `src/index.ts` and have other typescript helpers in `src/utils`.
The goal is to declare a global type so that the type is available in any source files.

I made a `global.d.ts` file in the project root.

```
import { Readable } from "stream";

declare global {
    type MyFile = {
        readonly name: string;
        readonly stream: Readable;
    }
}
```

But MyFile is not recognized in src files.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe you need to export the type? `export type MyFile`